# How can I get full PyCharm Code executing results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm to execute basic classification code in TensorFlow.
I have built the full code and the code consist of two stages: the first one for defining and compiling the model and the second one for the data visualizing.
However, when I'm trying to execute the full code, it executes it successfully but without showing me the result of the visualizing part.
I mean it shows me all training and evaluating results but without the showing the results of part two.
please any help !?

part 1:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.cm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(tf.__version__)

mnist= tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels)= mnist.load_data()
model= tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                   tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])


model.compile(optimizer= tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss= 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics= ['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)
```

part two:

```
 def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
    predictions_array, true_label, img= predictions_array[i], true_label[i], img[i]
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.imshow(img, cmap= plt.binary)
    plt.show()

    predicted_label= np.argmax(predictions_array)
    if predicted_label== true_label:
        color= 'blue'
    else:
        color= 'red'

    plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label], 100*np.max(predictions_array), class_names[true_label]), color=color)

def plot_value_array(i, predictions_array, true_label):
    predictions_array, true_label = predictions_array[i], true_label[i]
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    thisplot= plt.bar(range(10), predictions_array, color="#777777")
    plt.ylim([0,1])
    predicted_label= np.argmax(predictions_array)

    thisplot[predicted_label].set_color('red')
    thisplot[true_label].set_color('blue')

    i=0
    plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plot_image(i, predictions, test_labels, test_images)
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plot_value_array(i, predictions, test_labels)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: you have to execute your functions.

Comment: Hi, I've tried with that but there were no changes!

Comment: do you have all in one file ? You can add `print()` in functions to see if they were executed.

Comment: I added two print functions, one for the first ( def ) and another for the last one, when I run the code again it shows me just the last one.

Comment: if you see one text then you run only one of these function. How do you run it ? Do you have it all in one script ?